# Excel VBA Math just not adding up

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of code that's working perfectly and getting what I want but I'm a little confused as to how it's doing it??

**MyStr = "MANUFACTURER: LIEBHERR"**

Here's the code and the result:

**?VBA.Right(MyStr, VBA.Len(MyStr) - Application.Find(":", MyStr)-1) = LIEBHERR**

Perfect !!!!!!

So here's my question.

**?VBA.Len(MyStr) = 22**

**?Application.Find(":", MyStr)-1 = 12**

So combining the two statements above and using the VBA.Right command when I subtract 12 from 22 it looks to me that I should get 10 
but.......

**?VBA.Len(MyStr) - Application.Find(":", MyStr)-1 = 8**

Again, I'm getting what I want but I'm confused as to what I'm missing in my math???

Comment: I wouldn't use `Application.Find` in VBA code - you're looking for `Instr`.

Comment: `X-(y-1)` = `X-y+1`

Comment: 22-13-1=8  is result.

Comment: Comintern - I use both. Depends on which side of the bed I wake up on in the morning but yes, instr is the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its correct, the problem is you cant do `Application.Find(":", MyStr)-1` by itself:

`VBA.Len(MyStr) - Application.Find(":", MyStr)-1`

= 22 - 13 -1

= 9 - 1

= 8

You are mistakenly thinking of it as:

= 22 - ( 13 - 1 )

Comment: Valon thanks for the clarification. Now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark this as the correct answer if it resolved the issue you were experiencing.